# jdbi @sqlquery: could not determine data type of parameter $1

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbi

I am trying to add optional/nullable parameters to my sql query.

```
@SqlQuery("select * from temp where param1 = :param1")
List<Temp> findValues(@Bind("param1") String param1)
```

Problem: param can be null. So I tried to add null check in the sql query.

`SqlQuery("select * from temp where ( (:param1 is not null) and (param1 = :param1"))` 
This throws the following error:
org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1

In my problem I have to add multiple params all of which are nullable. (optional filters)

NOTE `coalesce(:param1, param1) = param1` : doesn't work quite right. If param1 is sent, it gives back results where value is either param1 value, or null.

How can I make this null check work? Or is there a way that I can generate the sql query and pass it as a string to @SqlQuery?

I have looked everywhere but can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that JDBI [`@Bind`'s](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/sqlobject/Bind.html) [default binder](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.kill-bill.billing/killbill-profiles-killbill/0.11.11/org/skife/jdbi/v2/sqlobject/DefaultObjectBinder.java) is not so smart when the value is `null`. On JDBC level, the [`setNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int)) method requires an SQL type, which it cannot extract for `null` values. I'm not that experienced in JDBI, so I cannot tell which is the right workaround for this.

Comment: ... but this seems to be a huge flaw in their API, if there is no easy workaround available.

Comment: However, on SQL level, you may just simply use casts, like `CAST(:param1 AS TEXT) IS NOT NULL`; that should work (but it's a rather ugly workaround).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it as optional filters, you could use @Define. Using @Define, you define attributes for the template engine to use(jdbi v2 uses [ST v3](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)). Then, your example would look like something like this:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM temp WHERE 1 = 1 <if(PARAM1)> AND param1 = :param1 <endif>)
List<Temp> findValues(@Define("PARAM1") @Bind("param1") String param1)
```

So, in this way, if value for param1 is null, query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE 1 = 1
```

otherwise:

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE 1 = 1 AND param1 = :param1
```